# Need query that filters entries by category

Tags: channel-entries, categories, query

I need to display entries from Channel 1 and entries from (Channel 2, Category 1).

I'm guessing the meat of the query would be something like this:

```
WHERE channel_id = 1 OR (channel_id = 2 AND cat_id = 175)
```

And this is the full query I'm trying to use, which isn't working:

```
{exp:query sql='SELECT t.entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles left join exp_category_posts p on p.entry_id = t.entry_id WHERE channel_id = 88 OR (channel_id = 11 AND cat_id = 192) LIMIT 8'}{entry_id}{/exp:query}
```

This is the error I'm getting: "Unknown column 't.entry_id' in 'field list'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined p as alias for the posts table but you have not defined t as alias for the titles table.

```
FROM exp_channel_titles t
```

You'll also probably want to limit by status and by date (not expired, not future-posted).